# Python can't connect to open socket on the same network

Tags: python, sockets

I have started a simple python socket, and I can freely connect to it from my **local** computer, but from iPad and another computer, I can't access it! What I am doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
from socket import socket

server = socket()
server.bind(("", 80))
server.listen(2)
message = """\
</pre><br><br><h1>Hi!</h1></body></html>
"""

while 1:
    c, a = server.accept()
    print "New connection from %s:%s"%tuple(a)
    c.sendall("<html><head><title>Hi!</title></head><body><pre>"+c.recv(4096*20)+message)
    c.close()
```

**EDIT**

Btw, I am using Linux Fedora 18. On Windows, I didn't have problems with sockets.

Comment: localhost (or empty only works for the local computer) when you try and connect from a different device on the same network make sure you are entering the ip that the socket is running on... also you may have to setup port forwarding on your router

Comment: Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself. See SSCCE.org for guidance.

Comment: Are you sure your other computers actually have the connectivity to your port 80? You can check by running `nc -lp 80`, then going to `http://<your-ip-address>/` on the other host.

Comment: @VasiliyFaronov, I am getting 'connection refused' error

Comment: @Vik2015 If, at the same time, going to `http://localhost/` from the 1st machine produces output in `nc`, this means you have a network problem. Firewall?

Comment: Ok, I will check it...

Answer (score 2):

In the [docs on socket](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.create_connection):

> If supplied, source_address must be a 2-tuple (host, port) for the socket to bind to as its source address before connecting. **If host or port are ‘’ or 0 respectively the OS default behavior will be used.**

The default behavior is likely to host on localhost. Try setting host to `"0.0.0.0"` to allow connectivity outside localhost.

Comment: Nope. Still can't connect from other devices.